# intel-pstate processor frequency very high even if in idle

Tags: scaling, idle, frequency, intel-cpu

I am running Ubuntu on my asus laptop with i7-4710HQ processor. I have some issue with cpu-freq scaling. When I use intel-pstate driver the frequency is always high (90% at 2.5GHz). I have read the post [High CPU Frequency at Idle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582805/high-cpu-frequency-at-idle) and change the kernel line parameters to disable intel-pstate driver and the cpu frequency scaling works perfectly but system do not use turbo mode (3.5GHz) even on AC.

Is it possible for the intel-pstate driver to work correctly?

Below some test I have made using cpufreq_histogram.

Fresh start without any additional programs start.

```
old cpufreq driver:
sudo ./cpufreq_histogram.sh 300
Collecting data for 300 seconds...
# NumSamples = 300; Min = 800.00; Max = 2100.00
# Mean = 856.000000; Variance = 36864.000000; SD = 192.000000; Median 800.000000
# each ∎ represents a count of 3
  800.0000 -   930.0000 [   284]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (94.67%)
  930.0000 -  1060.0000 [     2]:  (0.67%)
 1060.0000 -  1190.0000 [     0]:  (0.00%)
 1190.0000 -  1320.0000 [     3]: ∎ (1.00%)
 1320.0000 -  1450.0000 [     1]:  (0.33%)
 1450.0000 -  1580.0000 [     1]:  (0.33%)
 1580.0000 -  1710.0000 [     1]:  (0.33%)
 1710.0000 -  1840.0000 [     5]: ∎ (1.67%)
 1840.0000 -  1970.0000 [     1]:  (0.33%)
 1970.0000 -  2100.0000 [     2]:  (0.67%)

intel_pstate driver:
sudo ./cpufreq_histogram.sh 300
[sudo] hasło użytkownika mariusz: 
Collecting data for 300 seconds...
# NumSamples = 300; Min = 868.90; Max = 3500.30
# Mean = 2062.607000; Variance = 536898.224651; SD = 732.733393; Median 1789.700000
# each ∎ represents a count of 1
  868.9000 -  1132.0400 [    14]: ∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎ (4.67%)
 1132.0400 -  1395.1800 [    30]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (10.00%)
 1395.1800 -  1658.3200 [    84]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (28.00%)
 1658.3200 -  1921.4600 [    41]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (13.67%)
 1921.4600 -  2184.6000 [    16]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (5.33%)
 2184.6000 -  2447.7400 [    20]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (6.67%)
 2447.7400 -  2710.8800 [    38]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (12.67%)
 2710.8800 -  2974.0200 [     6]: ∎∎∎∎∎∎ (2.00%)
 2974.0200 -  3237.1600 [     8]: ∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎ (2.67%)
 3237.1600 -  3500.3000 [    43]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (14.33%)
```

Fresh start - chromium-browser with html5 video decoding.

```
Old cpufreq driver:
sudo ./cpufreq_histogram.sh 300
Collecting data for 300 seconds...
# NumSamples = 300; Min = 800.00; Max = 2300.00
# Mean = 974.666667; Variance = 44691.555556; SD = 211.403774; Median 900.000000
# each ∎ represents a count of 2
  800.0000 -   950.0000 [   182]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (60.67%)
  950.0000 -  1100.0000 [    71]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (23.67%)
 1100.0000 -  1250.0000 [    28]: ∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎ (9.33%)
 1250.0000 -  1400.0000 [     9]: ∎∎∎∎ (3.00%)
 1400.0000 -  1550.0000 [     0]:  (0.00%)
 1550.0000 -  1700.0000 [     2]: ∎ (0.67%)
 1700.0000 -  1850.0000 [     4]: ∎∎ (1.33%)
 1850.0000 -  2000.0000 [     3]: ∎ (1.00%)
 2000.0000 -  2150.0000 [     0]:  (0.00%)
 2150.0000 -  2300.0000 [     1]:  (0.33%)


intel_pstate driver:
sudo ./cpufreq_histogram.sh 300
Collecting data for 300 seconds...
# NumSamples = 300; Min = 800.00; Max = 3146.60
# Mean = 1847.854333; Variance = 230391.093281; SD = 479.990722; Median 1787.150000
# each ∎ represents a count of 1
  800.0000 -  1034.6600 [    13]: ∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎ (4.33%)
 1034.6600 -  1269.3200 [    25]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (8.33%)
 1269.3200 -  1503.9800 [    33]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (11.00%)
 1503.9800 -  1738.6400 [    73]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (24.33%)
 1738.6400 -  1973.3000 [    42]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (14.00%)
 1973.3000 -  2207.9600 [    31]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (10.33%)
 2207.9600 -  2442.6200 [    32]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (10.67%)
 2442.6200 -  2677.2800 [    46]: ∎∎∎∎∎ ... ∎∎∎∎∎ (15.33%)
 2677.2800 -  2911.9400 [     2]: ∎∎ (0.67%)
 2911.9400 -  3146.6000 [     3]: ∎∎∎ (1.00%)
```

Comment: My 3rd gen I-7 3630QM fluctuates between 1.2 Ghz and 3.4 Ghz nicely. After 2.4 Ghz is Turbo mode. As I'm typing the frequency is bouncing from 1260 Mhz to 1878 Mhz and many points in-between. I have 13 chrome tabs open one of them running Lord of the Rings on the external HDMI TV. I did invest a lot of time getting this and laptop temperature and fan speed to work properly. So keep plugging away and I hope you find success like I did.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have found a solution.

The intel_pstate driver has some problem with some Intel Hswell and later processors. Arch Linux users have noticed that this is the intel_pstate and the kernels internal timer problem. When timer is set to 300Hz (the default in arch) the intel_pstate driver is to sensitive. In Ubuntu this timer is set to 250Hz in a generic kernels.

When I test the linux-lowlatency kernel (whitch has set CONFIG_HZ to 1000) the problem seems to disappear (seems, because I have tested this in 4.11 lowlatency kernel and solution do not solve this problem). Battery lifetime increase from 2.5 to 4.5 hours for chrome html5video decoding. Below my test with lowlatency 4.10.0 kernel.

```
Collecting data for 62 seconds... 
# NumSamples = 62; Min = 799.80; Max = 3325.80
# Mean = 1332.198387; Variance = 413667.275965; SD = 643.169710; Median 1091.200000
# each ∎ represents a count of 1
  799.8000 -  1052.4000 [    29]: ∎∎∎∎∎∎∎...∎∎∎∎∎∎∎ (46.77%)
 1052.4000 -  1305.0000 [    14]: ∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎ (22.58%)
 1305.0000 -  1557.6000 [     3]: ∎∎∎ (4.84%)
 1557.6000 -  1810.2000 [     5]: ∎∎∎∎∎ (8.06%)
 1810.2000 -  2062.8000 [     3]: ∎∎∎ (4.84%)
 2062.8000 -  2315.4000 [     0]:  (0.00%)
 2315.4000 -  2568.0000 [     5]: ∎∎∎∎∎ (8.06%)
 2568.0000 -  2820.6000 [     0]:  (0.00%)
 2820.6000 -  3073.2000 [     0]:  (0.00%)
 3073.2000 -  3325.8000 [     3]: ∎∎∎ (4.84%)
```

Comment: Using the lowlatency kernel (atm 5.3.0-51-lowlatency with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS HWE) helps as well on my Surface Pro 3 with i7-4650U. It was fixed in a previous 5.3 kernel, but recently my frequency was around 3 GHz all the time again.